# Incoming call blocking in android 4.0

Tags: android

I want to block incoming calls for android 4.0 devices.I tried with ITelephony but its only working upto 2.2.But i found some apps in market its working in ICS too.Then i came to know that Modify phoine state has beed removed and only can apply to system apps but i tried with older android sdk there i kept modify phone state permission in manifest file it did not show me any error but after running the app its not working in ICS. Then i used below code

```
if (this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

but its not going inside the if clause in ICS even the permission is present in Manifest file, so what i suspect is it is not reading the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission from manifest file.

Please suggest me

Thank you in advance